# No vertical space between Bootstrap form groups

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

There are a few similar questions but none that really provide a solution for my issue (as far as I can see)

Here is my code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
        <input type="quantity" class="form-control" min="1" max="100" ng-model="formData.quantity" required />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
        <label for="type">Type:</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="type" ng-model="formData.type" required>
            <option value="240" selected>240</option>
            <option value="120">120</option>
        </select>
        <!--<input type="text" class="form-control" name="type" ng-model="formData.type"> -->
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
        <label for="type">Type 2:</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="typ2 ng-model="formData.typ2e" required>
            <option value="240" selected>240</option>
            <option value="120">120</option>
        </select>
        <!--<input type="text" class="form-control" name="type" ng-model="formData.type"> -->
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
<div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
    <a ui-sref="form.interests" class="btn btn-block btn-info">
    Next Section <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right"></span>
    </a>
</div>
</div>
```

Between the form groups there is no vertical spacing, it's all joined together one on top of the other. Not sure what to do. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: form-group class has custom css margin-bottom:15px; try to reset that into 0. hope it works.

Comment: You could add padding to the bottom (or top) of each form group div. really the spacing is up to you to customize with CSS

Comment: Perfect. Adding padding worked. Relatively new to Bootstrap. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap all the code with the form-horizontal

```
<div class="form-horizontal">your code</div>
```

Or add to your css file next code:

```
.form-group::before,
.form-group::after {
   content: " ";
   display: table;
}
```